# ggplot2 barplot for several categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, factors

I would like to create a barplot that shows different variables with the same factors. The dataset is like this

```
ID;Word;Excel;Power Point;Correo electronico
11;Intermedio;Intermedio;Intermedio;Intermedio
25;Intermedio;Intermedio;Intermedio;Intermedio
26;Básico;No la he utilizado;Básico;Básico
27;Básico;Básico;Básico;Intermedio
29;Intermedio;Intermedio;Intermedio;Avanzado
33;Avanzado;Intermedio;Avanzado;Avanzado
37;Avanzado;Básico;Intermedio;Avanzado
39;Intermedio;Intermedio;No la he utilizado;Intermedio
43;Intermedio;Intermedio;Intermedio;Intermedio
51;Avanzado;Básico;Intermedio;Avanzado
53;Intermedio;Intermedio;Intermedio;Intermedio
54;Intermedio;Intermedio;Básico;Avanzado
60;Intermedio;Intermedio;Intermedio;Intermedio
```

I would like to create a barplot like this
[barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETLJh.png)

I have created another barplot that shows all the information as I wanted but it is just with one variable:

```
ggplot(aes(x = Tablet, 
             y = prop.table(stat(count)), 
             fill = factor(Tablet), 
             label = scales::percent(prop.table(stat(count)), accuracy = 0.01))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = CColors)+
  
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")  + 
  geom_text( aes(label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..), accuracy = 0.01),
                 y= ((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat="count",
             vjust = -0.5,
             size = 3, 
             hjust=1)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  labs(y = 'Frecuencia relativa', fill = 'Uso de Tablet')+
  facet_wrap( ~ Sexo, nrow = 1)+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+ ggtitle(paste("Uso de Tablet para acceder a clases virtuales \nTotal: ", nrow(das), " Encuestados"))
```

The result is this
[Barplot with one variable and  grouped by Sex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKEGd.png)
Thanks for your help

Comment: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html

Comment: You need to change the data structure - one observation per row, one variable per column. Your new variables will be ID, software (levels: Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Email) and proficiency (levels: not used, basic, ..., advanced). You can tidy your data using the tidyr package. Then you can create a geom_bar with x = software and fill = proficiency. You do not need position = “dodge” to have the type of barplot you supplied in the link.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. Hoping this can help.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
#Load your data
Data <- structure(list(ID = c(11L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 33L, 37L, 39L, 
43L, 51L, 53L, 54L, 60L), Word = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Avanzado", "Básico", 
"Intermedio"), class = "factor"), Excel = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Básico", 
"Intermedio", "No la he utilizado"), class = "factor"), Power.Point = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Avanzado", 
"Básico", "Intermedio", "No la he utilizado"), class = "factor"), 
    Correo.electronico = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Avanzado", "Básico", 
    "Intermedio"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
#Melt data
Data.Melt <- melt(Data,id.vars = 'ID')
Data.Melt %>% group_by(variable,value) %>% summarise(N=n()) -> Dat1
#Plot
ggplot(Dat1,aes(x=variable,y=N,fill=value,label=N))+
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it made the job done. This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, here is what you should do to get the stacked bar plot you want.

Currently your data looks like this:

```
   ID       Word              Excel         PowerPoint Correo.electronico
2  11 Intermedio         Intermedio         Intermedio         Intermedio
3  25 Intermedio         Intermedio         Intermedio         Intermedio
4  26     Básico No la he utilizado             Básico             Básico
5  27     Básico             Básico             Básico         Intermedio
6  29 Intermedio         Intermedio         Intermedio           Avanzado
7  33   Avanzado         Intermedio           Avanzado           Avanzado
8  37   Avanzado             Básico         Intermedio           Avanzado
9  39 Intermedio         Intermedio No la he utilizado         Intermedio
10 43 Intermedio         Intermedio         Intermedio         Intermedio
11 51   Avanzado             Básico         Intermedio           Avanzado
12 53 Intermedio         Intermedio         Intermedio         Intermedio
13 54 Intermedio         Intermedio             Básico           Avanzado
14 60 Intermedio         Intermedio         Intermedio         Intermedio
```

You can tidy it to have one observation per row and one variable per column:

```
library(tidyr)
df_tidy <- df %>% pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "software")
df_tidy

# A tibble: 52 x 3
   ID    software           value             
   <chr> <chr>              <chr>             
 1 11    Word               Intermedio        
 2 11    Excel              Intermedio        
 3 11    PowerPoint         Intermedio        
 4 11    Correo.electronico Intermedio        
 5 25    Word               Intermedio        
 6 25    Excel              Intermedio        
 7 25    PowerPoint         Intermedio        
 8 25    Correo.electronico Intermedio        
 9 26    Word               Básico            
10 26    Excel              No la he utilizado
# … with 42 more rows
```

You can then plot your bar plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_tidy, aes(x = software, fill = value)) +
        geom_bar()
```

It looks like this:

[image]

You can then play with the axis labels and facet as required.